# What's wrong with my CREATE TABLE command?

Tags: postgresql

I'm following the instructions from this [document](http://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/pdf/8.4/postgresql-8.4-US.pdf). My exact version is 8.4.4.

This is what I try to do

```
CREATE TABLE testInfo (
               testNo integer PRIMARY KEY,
               product varchar(15),
               firmware varchar(15),
               startDate date,
               eta date
);
```

NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "testinfo_pkey" for table "testinfo"

It totally ignores my PRIMARY KEY constraint. I don't see whay this isn't essentially the same as the example in the docs.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
product_no integer PRIMARY KEY,
name text,
price numeric
```

)

I'm sure the obvious is staring me right in the face. Nevertheless I would appreciate any help offered.

Update: I just tried the example from the documentation, returns the same message. So may I conclude the documentation is in error, or that 8.4.4 is buggy?

Comment: How is it ignoring the `primary key` constraint?  Have you tried inserting duplicate values for `testNo`?

Comment: You mean the primary key testinfo_pkey doesn't use the column testNo? try `\d testInfo` from psql to see the table definition.

Comment: Which part of "NOTICE" do you interpret as error? This seems like a misunderstanding.

Comment: It was the "implicit index" wording. It suggested to me that I hadn't created a primary key so it was making one for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ignoring your primary key, it's telling you the mechanism it will use to enforce it.  This message can be disabled with client_min_messages (warning).

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was misinterpreting the message.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no Postgresql expert, but it appears the message is simply to inform you that an INDEX is being created to assist in the implementation of the PRIMARY KEY that you defined.